# Deserialising system object without "correct" constructor eg: ListChangedEventArgs

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I'm bundling a collection Hash and ListChangedEventArgs in a JSON message across a websocket so that a collection on the other end can be checked and synchronised. Serialising is fine, but when I try deserialise I'm getting the error:

> "Unable to find a constructor to use for type
>   System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs. A class should either have
>   a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor
>   marked with the JsonConstructor attribute."

I checked out the constructors for [ListChangedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.listchangedeventargs.listchangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) and there's a few overloads but nothing that the Json.Net deserialiser can use, and I don't think that C#5 supports constructor overloading. Can Json.Net work with an initialisation method instead of a constructor? There not being an empty default constructor for ListChangedEventArgs would still be an issue either way I guess..

Comment: Can't you create your own overload of ListChangedEventArgs and serialize that one?

Comment: @rene I guess that would work. I didn't know if there was some other syntactic magic that could be done, but I'll give that a go.

Comment: @rene base object doesn't have a parameterless constructor and parameters are read only once set, so I don't think a subclass will do it. There's always wrapping it in another class, and choosing the constructor based on the arguments but that's getting pretty messy.

Comment: It was worth trying...I agree on things getting messy...